# How to pick the best learning rate and optimizer using LearningRateScheduler

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have known the LearningRateScheduler from Coursera course but copying it the same way will result in poor model performance. Perhaps due to the range I set. The instructions from Keras website is limited.

```
def duo_LSTM_model(X_train, y_train, X_test,y_test,num_classes,batch_size=68,units=128, learning_rate=0.005, epochs=20, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2 ):

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout,return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout)))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
    RMSopt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-6)
    SGDopt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, decay=0.1, nesterov=False)


    lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(
    lambda epoch: 1e-8 * 10**(epoch / 20))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=adamopt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[lr_schedule])

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                                batch_size=batch_size)

    yhat = model.predict(X_test)

    return history, that
```

I have two questions.

1. How `1e-8 * 10**(epoch / 20)` does this work?
2. How should we choose the range for the 3 different optimizers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before answering the two questions in your post, let's first clarify `LearningRateScheduler` is not for picking the 'best' learning rate.

> **[It is an alternative to using a fixed learning rate is to instead vary the learning rate over the training process.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-rate-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/)**

I think what you really want to ask is "how to determine the best **initial** learning rate". If I am correct, then you need to learn about hyperparameter tuning.

---

**Answer to Q1:**

In order to answer how `1e-8 * 10**(epoch / 20)` works, let's create a simple regression task

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense

x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y = np.sin(x) + x**2

x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)

input_x = Input(shape=(1,))
y = Dense(10,activation='relu')(input_x)
y = Dense(1,activation='relu')(y)
model = Model(inputs=input_x,outputs=y)

adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)

def schedule_func(epoch):
    print()
    print('calling lr_scheduler on epoch %i' % epoch)
    print('current learning rate %.8f' % K.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
    print('returned value %.8f' % (1e-8 * 10**(epoch / 20)))
    return 1e-8 * 10**(epoch / 20)
    
lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule_func)

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=adamopt,metrics=['mae'])
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,
                    batch_size=8,
                    epochs=10,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[lr_schedule])
```

In the script above, instead of using a `lambda` function, I wrote a function `schedule_func`. Running the script, you will see that `1e-8 * 10**(epoch / 20)` just set the learning rate for each `epoch`, and the learning rate is increasing.

**Answer to Q2:**

There are a bunch of nice posts, for example

1. [Setting the learning rate of your neural network.](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/nn-learning-rate/)
2. [Choosing a learning rate](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/410/39501)

Comment: In order to test the best learning rate. Shall I set the epoch to be 160 so it ranges from 1e-8 to 1 for all the three types of optimizers then decide which to pick?

Comment: @Leo I think you misunderstand `lr_schedule`, it is not for finding the best learning rate, it is for adjusting the learning rate during the training process (say training for 100 epochs). If you want to find the best learning rate that is a completely different story, google hyperparameter optimization.